# $L$ is a class of languages that cannot be represented by a regular expression. How to state cardinality of $L$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

$L$ is a class of languages  that cannot be represented by a regular expression.

The book says that the cardinality of $L$ is $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$

1. what's the logic behind getting the cardinality of $L$?
2. how does $|L| = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

thank you!!

Comment: The class of all languages that cannot be represented by regular expressions is a proper class, so it’s too big even to have a cardinality, unless you restrict the allowable symbols in the alphabet to some predefined set. If the set of allowable symbols is countable, then you do get $|L|=2^{\aleph_0}$. Exactly what limitations on the alphabets does your source impose?

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix a finite alphabet $\Sigma$, the class of all language is $P(\Sigma^*)$ and has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Now, the regular languages $R$ are countable, since for instance regular expressions are countable (they can be encoded by words on a finite alphabet). But $L=P(\Sigma^*)\setminus R$. Since $|P(\Sigma^*)|=2^{\aleph_0}$ and $|R|=\aleph_0$ we get $|L|=2^{\aleph_0}$